# Automação de teste (Diminuir a velocidade de execução)

Tags: testes, testes-funcionais

Como diminuir a velocidade de execução dos testes no katalon Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente alterar a propriedade `Delay Between actions` conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez isso possa te ajudar.